# Displaying MySQL results in two columns (editing existing code)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been asked to revise an existing site, it's still using PHP5.3 and an old version of PHPmyDirectory, and the code is a little messy.

I'm trying to revise it to just display the list of cities in two columns. I'm trying to do it as a table, as it seemed easiest, but I could also just pull the results into to side by side divs, as there are never more than 26 cities listed (so first half or first 13 in div one, the rest in div two).

Here's the existing original code (I know its not mysqli, but we'll be redoing this site shortly so there's no sense trying to redo a million pages of code right now):

```
function create_service_area($title) {

        global $listing;
        $sql = "SELECT state_id, city_id FROM " .T_LISTINGS_CITIES. " WHERE listing_id = {$listing['id']} " ;
        $result = query($sql);
        if(!$result){
             $output = "<p>Call for Service Area!</p>";
             } 
                else {
                   $output = "<p>";
                   $result_array = array();
                   while ($service = fetch_array($result))
                    { 

                    $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
                    $result2 = query($sql2);

                        if(!$result2){
                        break;
                        } else {
                                    while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2))
                                     {
                                        $output .=  "{$service2['title']}";
                                        $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
                                        $result_array[] = $title_array;                                                             
                                        }
                        $output .= "<br/>";
                        }


                    }
                    if($listing['custom_103'] =="Yes") {
                        $output .= "<b>".$title." will travel for an additional fee!</b></p>";
                    } else {
                        $output .="</p>";   
                    }

                }


        return $output;

        }
```

This is what is looks like currently: [Current Site](http://www.aboutfacesentertainment.com/entertainers/caricature-artists/l/united-states/georgia/greater-atlanta-area/atlanta-ga/tony-s-caricature-artists.html)

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
function create_service_area($title) {

global $listing;
$sql = "SELECT state_id, city_id FROM " .T_LISTINGS_CITIES. " WHERE listing_id = {$listing['id']} " ;
$result = query($sql);

    if(!$result){

        $output = "<p>Call for Service Area!</p>";
        } 
    else {
        $result_array = array();
        while ($service = fetch_array($result)) { 

                $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
                $result2 = query($sql2);
                $i=0;

                if(!$result2) {
                    break;
                    } 
                    else {
                        while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2)) {

                                $output .=  "{$service2['title']}";
                                $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
                                $result_array[] = $title_array;
                                $i++;                                                               
                            }
                      echo "<table>";
                        for ($j=0; $j<$i; $j=$j+2) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$title_array[$j]."</td><td>".$title_array[$j+1]."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    echo "</table>";
                    }


                }
                if($listing['custom_103'] =="Yes") {
                        $output .= "<p><b>".$title." will travel for an additional fee!</b></p>";
                    } 
                    else {
                        $output .="";   
                    }

                }

return $output;                 
}
```

And here's what I'm getting: [DEV site](http://www.bluetabby.com/aboutfacesentertainment/entertainers/caricature-artists/l/united-states/georgia/greater-atlanta-area/atlanta-ga/tony-s-caricature-artists.html)

I'm very much a PHP newbie, and my understanding is pretty spotty, but I've tried a bunch of different solutions I've found here, and can't get them to work. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I believe 1998 just called to have its website back. Going to look into it.

Comment: Indent properly so you can see what's in what loop. Honestly, how can you get anything working with this awful indenting?

Comment: Also, go ahead and put the opening bracket `{` on a new line.  You don't get more performance by sparing newlines. Egyptian brackets don't gain you anything but unreadability.

Comment: Oh God, I know right? I'm SLOWLY moving them to redesign, but for now am supporting that extremely outdated site :)

Comment: In your for lus you are creating tables over and over again, which is not the thing you want?

Comment: This awful indenting is not mine, I try to clean up some as I go, but really, when dealing with countless pages and pages of code, I don't do much clean-up. Sorry.

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is create a loop of TD's with appropriate </tr><tr> added as needed (after every second result)

Comment: @Haikukitty no but you could've cleaned it up for us, the poor mortal souls reviewing this code :-( *weeps*

Comment: You're right! Sorry, was rushing. I will try to edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Kim's code, I was able to get it working with some revisions. I also scrapped the table for divs, since it seems less messy to me and it seemed like the table styling was interfering somehow.

```
function create_service_area($title) {

    global $listing;
    $sql = "SELECT state_id, city_id FROM " .T_LISTINGS_CITIES. " WHERE listing_id = {$listing['id']} " ;
     $result = query($sql);
    if(!$result){
    $output = "<p>Call for Service Area!</p>";
        } else {
        $output = "<div>";
        //$result_array = array();
        $even_odd=true;
        while ($service = fetch_array($result))
            {

            $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
            $result2 = query($sql2);

                if(!$result2){
                    break;
                } else {
                    $output .=  "{$service2['title']}";
                    $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
                    $result_array[] = $title_array;

                while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    if ($even_odd) {
                        $output .=  '<div style="float:left;width:50%;">'."{$service2['title']}".'</div>';
                        $even_odd=false;
                    } else {
                        $output .=  '<div style="float:right;width:50%;">'."{$service2['title']}".'</div>';
                        $even_odd=true;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        if($listing['custom_103'] =="Yes") {
        $output .= "<div style='clear:both;width:90%;float:none;'><p><b>".$title." will travel for an additional fee!</b></p></div>";
         } else {

        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Thanks so much Kim and Mouser!

Answer (score 1):

if I got it correct you should change your

```
else {
    $output = "<p>";
    $result_array = array();
    while ($service = fetch_array($result))
    {

        $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
        $result2 = query($sql2);

        if(!$result2){
            break;
        } else {
            while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2))
            {
                $output .=  "{$service2['title']}";
                $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
                $result_array[] = $title_array;
            }
            $output .= "<br/>";
        }


    }
    if($listing['custom_103'] =="Yes") {
        $output .= "<b>".$title." will travel for an additional fee!</b></p>";
    } else {
        $output .="</p>";
    }

}
```

with

```
else {
    $output = "<table>";
    $result_array = array();
    $even_odd=true;
    while ($service = fetch_array($result))
    {

        $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
        $result2 = query($sql2);

        if(!$result2){
            break;
        } else {
            $output .= "";

            while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2))
            {
                if ($even_odd) {
                    $output .=  '<tr><td>'."{$service2['title']}".'</td>';
                    $even_odd=false;
                } else {
                    $output .=  '<td>'."{$service2['title']}".'</td></tr>';
                    $even_odd=true;
                }
                $output .=  "{$service2['title']}";
                $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
                $result_array[] = $title_array;
            }

        }


    }
    if($listing['custom_103'] =="Yes") {
        $output .= "<b>".$title." will travel for an additional fee!</b></p>";
    } else {
        if (!$even_odd)$output .="<td></td></tr>"; 
        $output .="</table>";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction but doesn't create a city list over two columns. It just divides the city and state over two columns

Comment: OH! So, I've got it totally wrong then. I need to scrap that [$j] and [j+1] reference? Are you saying that's calling city in one td and state in another?

Comment: @Kim - this is closer! I see the table formatting, but its populating below the other content, and I'm still getting the original results strung together without spaces... any clue as to why? See updated page: http://www.bluetabby.com/aboutfacesentertainment/entertainers/caricature-artists/l/united-states/georgia/greater-atlanta-area/atlanta-ga/tony-s-caricature-artists.html
Also - thank you! This is definitely moving me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I couldn't test it of course, since I've got no access to the data being loaded.

```
echo "<table>";
$result_array = array();
while ($service = fetch_array($result))
{ 
    //this will loop multiple times. 7 times for Tony S. in the example.

    $sql2 = "SELECT title FROM " .T_LOCATIONS. " WHERE id = {$service['city_id']} " ;
    $result2 = query($sql2);
    $i=0;
    if(!$result2)
    {
        break;
    } 
    else 
    {
        while ($service2 = fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $title_array = explode(',', $service2['title']);
            $result_array[] = $title_array;

            $i++;                                                               
        }
    }

}

for ($j=0; $j < count($result_array); $j++)
{
    if ($j % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$result_array[$j][0]." (".$result_array[$j][1].")</td>";
    if ($j % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    if ($j % 2 == 1 && $j == count($result_array)-1)
    {
        echo "<td></td></tr>";
    }
}       
echo "</table>";
```

Paste and replace between this lines:

```
if(!$result){

    $output = "<p>Call for Service Area!</p>";
    } 
else {
  .... PASTE IN HERE ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mouser! I tried this in place - its doing something odd, repeating the results twice, but not in a table. I wonder why I keep getting duplicates... see: http://www.bluetabby.com/aboutfacesentertainment/entertainers/caricature-artists/l/united-states/georgia/greater-atlanta-area/atlanta-ga/tony-s-caricature-artists.html
ETA: Actually - I see what its doing, Its adding the +1 loop to add each new city to previous result and then repeating the updated result.

Comment: I deleted the return $output at the bottom of original function. Should I not have or is that not even what you're talking about? :)

Comment: I copied the code in again, did you already change it? I'm seeing the same thing, I think: http://www.bluetabby.com/aboutfacesentertainment/entertainers/caricature-artists/l/united-states/georgia/greater-atlanta-area/atlanta-ga/tony-s-caricature-artists.html

Comment: Yes I did. I moved the for lus out of the while loop.